# Getting Error in Project during start project with Npm start, Project created with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babel-jest

I am using ubantu 16 OS and i have installed

> Node version v10.13.0 and npm version 6.4.1

I am creating Reactjs project based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I have created project using command

```
sudo npm init react-app my-app
```

This command successfully created my-app, but when i am running project using **npm start**
command under my-app folder i am getting following error

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /home/karan/workspace/1425/my-app
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "23.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically. However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  /home/karan/workspace/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 22.4.4) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /home/karan/workspace/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

As this is showing issue related

> react-scripts start ,"babel-jest": "23.6.0"

but i am new to js framework(node/npm/react), how this problem will resolve please help?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not use 'create-react-app'?

Comment: @Xorifelse facing same problem with create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're receiving an `ELIFECYCLE` error and not an `EACCES`, maybe it's something related to the fact that you used `sudo` to run the command. Try to create and run the project again, without sudo.

Follow this [guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) for more details on how to do it.

Comment: Hi Lucsrods, I have go throw guild, and still facing same issue.